# Pagination on a page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I've got a page of which I'm displaying a load of custom post type posts, much like blog displays a load of posts.

I'm using `WP_Query` and have my pagination links outputting correctly, however when I navigate to the page 2 url (`/my_page/page/2`) I get a 404, not surprising because I think WordPress thinks I want sub pages... but I don't, I want that value as the paged value.

Is there a way to enable this on a specific page?

Comment: Already tried `get_query_var( 'paged' );`? If not: search for that (via google) on the site.

Comment: That would work on the designated blog page, but this is just a standard page. WordPress must think I want sub pages `page` and `2`... I don't.

Comment: Ah, ok. You ain't got IDs like this in custom permalinks (unless you haven't set them up to append the ID). Your ID is replaced by your page slug for e.g. `/my_page`. If you then add `/page` it does a lookup (depending on your rewrite rules) for `page/paged` query var with the value `2`. You need to add much more info to that question.

Answer (score 1):

in that Archive page, where you have your pagination (did you create it?) use add_query_arg('paged', (int)get_query_var( 'paged' )+1); for the 'next page' href.

Also, [WP Page-Navi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) is a GREAT and easy way to add pagination to your archive-post_type.php file